# DateTimes near a DST changeover do not accurately survive a WriteXML/ReadXML roundtrip. How to preserve them?

Tags: c#, datetime, dataset, xml-serialization, dst

I recently had an issue that I traced to the fact that when I serialize/deserialize a DataSet to and from XML using WriteXML/ReadXML at very specific times near a DST changeover, the DateTimes are not preserved.  I'm running this on a computer set to Eastern Time, which has a -5 offset from UTC.

It looks like this affects any UTC time that, if converted to local time and then back to UTC, would land on a time that doesn't "exist" in local time.  Ie, March 12 2:01 AM doesn't "exist" in Eastern Time because the clocks would have jumped ahead to 3AM, and the code appears to do that somewhere under the covers.

How can I solve this?  The following is a self-contained C# program that demonstrates the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Data;

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataSet data = new DataSet();
        data.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
        data.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        data.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new DateTime(2023, 3, 12, 2, 1, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));

        string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        data.WriteXml(path, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

        data = new DataSet();
        data.ReadXml(path);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Date is {data.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]}");

        // Run this code on a computer with a timezoen that adjusts for DST.

        // Expected output: Date is 3/12/2023 2:01:00 AM
        // Actual output:   Date is 3/12/2023 3:01:00 AM

        // March 12 2AM is when the clocks "jump ahead" for DST.  It looks like the
        // conversion through WriteXML/ReadXML is determining that 2AM is not a
        // "valid" time, and is helpfully correcting it to 3AM.  However, since the
        // time is UTC this makes no sense.  How can I avoid this?

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am temporarily working around this via the hideous hack of returning datetimes from SQL as formatted strings, then parsing the exact UTC from those strings.  This is not a long-term solution.

Comment: Have you tried `DateTimeOffset` class instead of `DateTime`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could handle this:

- Option 1: Set the `DateTimeMode` property of the column to `DataSetDateTime.Utc`.

  ```
  var dc = data.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
  dc.DateTimeMode = DataSetDateTime.Utc;
  ```
- Option 2: Use a `DateTimeOffset` type instead of a `DateTime`.

  ```
  data.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTimeOffset));
  data.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new DateTimeOffset(2023, 3, 12, 2, 1, 0, TimeSpan.Zero));
  ```